# MYSQL: Inserting time period OR time/moment

Tags: mysql

I want to build a little calendar system for my website.

When the user creates an appointment he can choose between a time period (like 3rd march to 7th march) and a concrete day with time/moment (like 3rd march 2016 11:00).

I want to insert this into the mysql database.

**Values for inserting a time period:**

date1: 3rd march 2016

date2: 7th march 2016

**Values for inserting a concrete day with time:**

datetime: 3rd march 2016 11:00

**Now the question I stuck on: How should the table look like?**

I thought on sth like this (only the columns):
`id | appointment | date1 | date2 | datetime1`

And when the user inserts a time period the datetime-field would be empty. But is this the way to go?

Comment: You just have to use only two DateTime columns to store. As you can change date to any format while fetching the data from the table. While inserting the data in DateTime type column , Make sure that Date Time should be in format like `2015-07-31 11:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```
id
appointment
startdate
starttime (empty if it is an entry for a whole day)
enddate (empty if it is a single entry without a period)
endtime (empty if it is an entry for a whole day)
```